# Editting a serialized file

Tags: java

I have used this code to write 10 records/objects on a serialized file, now I want to modify/edit only 6th record/object written on the file keeping other records/objects same. Please tell how I can do that???

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;  
import java.io.FileOutputStream;  
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;  
import java.io.Serializable;  
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class Write {     

    public static void main(String arg[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

        ObjectOutputStream to = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.cer"));
        Scanner out = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name;
        Double age;

        System.out.println("write NAME and AGE otherwise ctrl+z to teminate.");
        while(out.hasNext()) {
            name=out.nextLine();
            age=out.nextDouble();
            to.writeObject(new Data(name,age));
            System.out.println("write NAME and AGE otherwise ctrl+z to teminate.");
        }
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Ended");
    }
}

class Data implements Serializable {

    String name;
    Double age;

    public Data(String name, Double age) {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to load all the objects and rewrite them

Comment: I might point out, although it might be a mute point at this stage, object serialization was intended for the short term storage of objects, typically for transmission over the wire or for RPC purposes.  It is not a suitable long term storage mechanism. You might consider using JAXB instead (as an example)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will be possible to edit any particular object in a file. What you will have to do is,

1. Read all data from file.
2. Edit the object you want.
3. Overwrite the previous data.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to modify/edit only 6th record/object written on the file keeping other records/objects same. Please tell how I can do that?

You can't, in practice. The serialized stream contains block markers and data counts and all kinds of things that make it impossible in general.